# How to prevent related object persistence in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, materialized-views

***Environment***:

- python 3.7
- SqlAlchemy 1.3.10 (I also tested on 1.2.16, same result)
- PostgreSQL 11

***TL,DR:*** I have a table and a 1-1 "related" materialized view (no fk, the relation is implicit on the sql side). In SQLAlchemy this relationship is declared as `viewonly=True`. But if I assign to it, the session tries to insert the assigned mat view object anyway (which fails because it's a materialized view, obviously).

**Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `viewonly` or is the relationship not set up properly?**

**Complete reproducible test case**:

- setup a python 3.7 venv with SQLalchemy 1.3.10
- create a new (empty) postgresql database
- save this code sample in a file and change the DB_URI value to the one you just created
- execute the file within the env (`python <path-to-script>`)

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import unittest
from unittest import TestCase

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, DeclarativeMeta
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker, object_session

create_sql = """
CREATE TABLE universe (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   is_perfect BOOLEAN NULL DEFAULT 'f'
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW answer AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        trunc(random() * 100)::INT AS computed
    FROM universe
)
"""


Base: DeclarativeMeta = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata


class Universe(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'universe'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)
    is_perfect = sa.Column(sa.Boolean, nullable=False, server_default='f')

    answer: Answer = relationship('Answer',
                                  backref=backref('universe', uselist=False),
                                  innerjoin=False,
                                  lazy='select',
                                  uselist=False,
                                  viewonly=True)

    def set_perfect(self):
        self.is_perfect = (self.answer.computed == 42)

        session = object_session(self)
        if session:
            session.commit()


class Answer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'answer'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('universe.id'), primary_key=True)
    computed = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)


DB_URI = 'postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/db_name'  # Fill in your own
engine = sa.create_engine(DB_URI)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=True)
session = Session()


class UniverseTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        session.execute("DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS answer")
        session.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS universe")
        session.execute(create_sql)
        session.execute("INSERT INTO universe (id, name) VALUES (1, 'HG2G');")
        session.commit()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        session.execute("DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW answer")
        session.execute("DROP TABLE universe")
        session.commit()
        session.close()

    def test__is_perfect(self):
        universe: Universe = session.query(Universe).get(1)

        universe.answer = Answer(id=1, computed=42)
        universe.set_perfect()
        assert universe.is_perfect is True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As you can see, during the test, I assign a fake `Answer(id=1, computed=42)` to `universe.answer` to test the method `.set_perfect()`.

The test errors out during the `set_perfect()` function because the call to `session.commit()` tries to commit the `Answer(id=1, computed=42)` object along with the updated field on the `Universe` object.

A sample of the error message

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) cannot change materialized view "answer"

[SQL: INSERT INTO answer (id, computed) VALUES (%(id)s, %(computed)s)]
[parameters: {'id': 1, 'computed': 42}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

For SQLAlchemy 1.3.10 (the version I was using for this example) and below, the fix is to set `cascade` on the relationship to either `None`, or one of the non-persistence related cascade options (`"expunge"`, `"refresh-expire"` or both). `False` (the default) won't work because it means `"save-update, merge"`.

To sum up:

```py
answer: Answer = relationship(
    'Answer',
    ...,
    viewonly=True,
    cascade=None  # or "expunge" or "refresh-expire" or "expunge,refresh-expire"
)
```

This was indeed a bug of versions 1.3 and below which was corrected somewhere between 1.3.11 and 1.4.22. All I know is that the original example, which doesn't specify `cascade`, works like a charm in 1.4.22.

Related bug-reports:

- [GitHub issue 4993](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4993)
- [GitHub issue 4994](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4994)

And the corresponding changelogs:

- [persistence related cascade operations disallowed with viewonly true](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_14.html#persistence-related-cascade-operations-disallowed-with-viewonly-true).